# How to translate Chinese web page to English on Firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, browser-addons, translation, chinese

How to translate  Chinese  web page to English on Firefox ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with [google tranlate](http://translate.google.com)
or use this [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3361)

Answer (score 2):

Google Translate!